# VBA Code Not Working And returning blank Value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

HTML Code From which I want to fetch span data into my Excel workbook

```
<div id="module_product_title_1" class="pdp-block module">
<div class="pdp-product-title">
<div class="pdp-mod-product-badge-wrapper">
<img src="laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/…" class="pdp-mod-product-badge" alt="badge">
<span class="pdp-mod-product-badge-title" data-spm-anchor-id="a2a0e.pdp.0.i0.5b4b476dTBie86">Bosch WAW32560GC - Front Load Automatic Washing Machine - 9Kg
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

VBA Code That I am using to perform the action

```
For i = Sr To Er
DoEvents
MSXML.Open "GET", Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
MSXML.send
DoEvents
lr = i
DOC.body.innerHTML = MSXML.responseText
On Error Resume Next
Sheet2.Range("A" & lr).Value = DOC.getElementByTagName("span").Item(0).innerText.getElementByClassName("pdp -Product - Title").Item(0).innerText
```

Comment: Please update your question with your `HTML` code. It is illegible in comments

Comment: HTML Is added in the question now. Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096264/how-to-get-data-from-span asked within 30 minutes

Comment: The answer to that thread in incomplete as the questioner ran away.

Comment: @ZohaibAfroze your question is not a question, Doesn't work is not a question. Please  read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: I tried my best to improve the question. @Damian please help me.

Comment: The class name in your code doesn't match the class name in your HTML.

Comment: Please share the proper VBA code by inserting the proper class name with me so that I can check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `.getElementByTagName`. The method you're looking for is `.getElementsByTagName()` and it returns a collection of elements.

Also this:

```
DOC.getElementByTagName("span").Item(0).innerText.getElementByClassName("pdp -Product - Title").Item(0).innerText
```

makes no sense even if the method you were using was the right one, because the `.innerText` property of an HTML element will return a string and not another HTML element from which you can get elements by class name.

To access the `i-th` element of the collection of `<span></span>` elements you would have to do it like so:

```
DOC.getElementsByTagName("span")(i-1) 'indexing starts from 0
```

To get this element's inner text you use the corresponding property of that element:

```
DOC.getElementsByTagName("span")(i-1).innerText
```

If you want your reference to be more specific you can even do this:

```
DOC.getElementById("module_product_title_1").getElementsByTagName("span")(i-1).innerText
```

Which means that, you first find the unique element whose ID is `module_product_title_1` and then you "search" that element for any `<span></span>` elements and get access to the `i-th` of these elements.